# Cordova geolocation

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, cordova-plugins

I went through [this](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html) tutorial and end up with:
[image]
I'm also not able to send coordinates to the emulator under Open Perspectives > DDMS > Emulator Control > Location Control
[image]

Comment: get close to the window , I thought that the app didn't work but it actually worked when I get close to the window because I guess you are in a room or something and receiving gps data is not easy